# Had its place? What does it mean? And others

Tags: meaning, commas, clauses

I've run into a sentence like the following and have few questions.

> The pot cup which was on the wooden trestle on the left, had its place in the Bible, when Jesus pleads with God.

First of all why ", had its place in the Bible," is there comma on the beginning and at the end? Is it because is it non-defining relative clause?
So could we say "which had its place in the Bible" which is omitted?

And what is the thing that "had its place in the Bible"? Is it the pot cup?

And should I understand from "had its place in the Bible" like "exist in the Bible" or "which could be found in the Bible"?

So basically what does it mean?

Comment: Hi. Where does this quotation come from? Please provide a link.

Comment: At least by conventions of US English, there should be a comma before the *which*. If you add one there, then the comma after *left* makes sense. (In US English, if there is no comma after *cup*, then it should be *that*, not *which*, that is used. And, if that is the case, then the comma after *left* is strange.)

Comment: A friend of mine asked me this question. I wanted a link. If he provides, I'll return you here.

Comment: Presumably 'a cup like that one is mentioned in a Bible story, when...'

Comment: We may only ask one question per post.

Comment: The comma between the subject and verb is considered nigh-on verboten nowadays, though you can still find the odd 'authority' licensing it for very long and especially clause-containing subjects (as here). // Adding a comma after 'The pot cup' would make the which-clause non-defining and would mandate the (now second) comma after 'left'. Then the subject would be reduced to 'The pot cup'.

Answer (score 0):

Had its place is an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+place+in) that means:

> Played a role in some activity.  Was appropriate in.

As for the punctuation, this is completely non-standard and adds nothing to the understanding of the meaning.

It should likely be:

> The pot cup, which was on the wooden trestle on the left, had its place in the Bible when Jesus pleads with God.

Punctuated thusly, it makes *which was on the wooden trestle on the left* a parenthetical statement which identifies which pot cup in particular we're discussing here.

Punctuation, unfortunately, is mostly a matter of style.  It's primary function should be to clarify meaning.  So, as such, no one can make an authoritative statement on the propriety of a comma's placement.  Instead, one can point you to a manual of style which contains recommendations which help to make your point properly understood.

Comment: I don't disagree with your comments, simply that I think you are taking a lot on trust - I can't make out with any certainty what this sentence is actually trying to say, I would not like to make this suggestion without a bit more context, as Spencer suggests.

Comment: @NeilB The idiom is the idiom.  The punctuation as I said, is speculation.

Comment: I'll give the link as soon as my friend provide me. This punctuation makes sense at least. Actually I couldn't understand what was saying in the first place but after your comment it is more clear now.